# glGenTextures gives GL_INVALID_OPERATION despite valid OpenGL context

Tags: opengl, qtopengl

I get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error when calling `glGenTextures` and I have no idea what could be responsible for it.

I am using QtOpenGLWidget to retrieve the context and it looks valid  at the time I call `glGenTextures()` (at least I have one since `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` and `glxGetCurrentContext()` both return something which is not crap)

The faulty code is called from the `QOpenGLWidget::resizeGL()` method. In the `QOpenGLWidget::initializeGL()` I compile successfully some shader programs and I create / upload data to VAO / VBOs.

So my questions are :

- What are the common faulty cases of `glGenTextures()` except not having an OpenGL context at all
- Can an OpenGL context be invalid or messed up and, in such a case
- How can I check that my OpenGL context is valid ?

EDIT: Since I strongly believe this is related to the fact my machine has no proper GPU, [here is the return of glxinfo](https://gist.github.com/Zouch/7f011dd18d7a9093ba8734d1ca0f16a0).

Comment: you need to post your code.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the problem. It appears a shader was silently not compiling properly (hardcoded shader not checked for proper compilation, with incorrect #version) and that was messing up the next OpenGL error check which was the `glGenTextures()`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it is the `glGenTextures()` call, that causes the error. This call can only throw GL_INVALID_ENUM and GL_INVALID_VALUE. Most likely some other call is wrong and the `bind()` of the new texture is the invalid call.

Try to localise your offending call with `glGetError()`.

You can check the documentation for possible failures of gl calls here:
https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glCreateTextures.xhtml